# How to make window transparent in VisionOS

Tags: swiftui, visionos

How to make window transparent in Vision OS, while keeping the content of the window as is?

```
WindowGroup {
  TabView {
    ViewWithTransparentBackground().tabItem {} // how to create this view?
    ViewWithDefaultBackground().tabItem {}
  }
}
```

I tried `ViewWithTransparentBackground().background(.clear)`, but it doesn't seem to work.